# ServerScriptService.Script:42: Expected ')' (to close '(' at column 67), got ','

Tags: lua, syntax-error, roblox

Im new to Roblox Lua scripting and while practicing my dynamic function skills, I found an error that I cant fix. The error is the title of this post. I tried messing around with brackets like adding new ones and deleting some, but i cant fix it. Heres the code, thanks.

```
    local mypart = Instance.new("Part")
    mypart.Name = name
    mypart.Transparency = 0.5
    mypart.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Burgundy")
    mypart.Position = Vector3.new(5,5,5)
    mypart.Anchored = anchored
    mypart.Material = ("Ice")
    mypart.Parent = game.Workspace
    mypart.Reflectance = reflectance
end
generatePart("ArgumentOne", false, 0.7)
generatePart("ArgumentTwo", false, 0.7)

function owo(name, material, anchored, color)
    local gamermove = Instance.new("Part")
    gamermove.Name = name
    gamermove.Position = Vector3.new(9,9,9)
    gamermove.Transparency = 0.5
    gamermove.Anchored = anchored
    gamermove.BrickColor = color
    gamermove.CanCollide = true
    gamermove.Material = material
    gamermove.Parent = game.Workspace
end

owo("LoLoLolsoawdoaldowalda", ("Ice"), false, BrickColor.new("Black"))
owo("asdaasdasda", ("Ice"), false, BrickColor.new("Beige"))
owo("dawsdajkdnaw", ("Ice"), false, BrickColor.new("Bright bluish green"))

function gamer(name, transparency, anchored, material, parent, CanCollide, Vectorisa)
    local gamer = Instance.new("Part")
    gamer.Name = name 
    gamer.Transparency = transparency
    gamer.Anchored = anchored
    gamer.Material = material
    gamer.Parent = parent
    gamer.CanCollide = CanCollide
    gamer.Position = Vectorisa
end

gamer(("Free6ix9ine"), 0.5, false, ("Ice"), game.Workspace, true, (10,10,10)
```

Comment: Append `)` at the end of your file.

Answer (score 0):

Read the error message

> ServerScriptService.Script:42: Expected ')' (to close '(' at column
> 67), got ','

Go to line 42 of your code

```
gamer(("Free6ix9ine"), 0.5, false, , (10,10,10)("Ice"), game.Workspace, true, (10,10,10)
```

In your head from inside out remove anything that is looking ok

```
("Free6ix9ine"), 0.5, false, , (10,10,10)("Ice"), game.Workspace, true, (10,10,10)
```

so what's left is

```
gamer(
```

which looks kind of incomplete, don't you think?

Use a text editor that autocompletes everything that comes in pairs and highlights any of them who stand alone.